# JavaScript retrieving a innerHTML value from a class that uses multiple tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I'm building a JavaScript calculator, and I have the class numerical, and whenever that class gets click it iterates a code sequence as you can see in my javascript below, but it won't retrieve the innerHTML value of the one it clicked for some reason. Do I need to move on to ID's or can I make this work?

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.numerical').on('click', function(){
        var innerDisp = document.getElementById('display').innerHTML;
        var num = document.getElementById(this).innerHTML;
        document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = innerDisp + num;
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<body>
    <center>
        <div id="calculator">
            <div id="display"></div>
            <button class="numerical" id="0">0</button>
            <button class="numerical" id="1">1</button>
            <button class="numerical" id="2">2</button>
            <button class="function" id="add">+</button>
            <button class="numerical" id="3">3</button>
            <button class="numerical" id="4">4</button>
            <button class="numerical" id="5">5</button>
            <button class="function" id="subtract">-</button>
            <button class="numerical" id="6">6</button>
            <button class="numerical" id="7">7</button>
            <button class="numerical" id="8">8</button>
            <button class="function" id="multiply">x</button>
            <button class="numerical" id="9">9</button>
            <button class="function" id="c">C</button>
            <button class="function" id="ce">CE</button>
            <button class="function" id="divide">/</button>
        </div>
    </center>
    <script src="calculator.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
        var num = document.getElementById(this).innerHTML;
```

doesn't make sense. In your event handler, `this` will refer to your element itself. There's no need to fetch it again, and even if there were that wouldn't do it.

You're coding with jQuery, so your handler can be just this:

```
$('.numerical').on('click', function(){
    $('#display').html($(this).html());
    // or this:
    // $('#display').html(this.innerHTML); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont use innerHtml for that. Buttons are form controls, just use their value attr and avoid parsing the DOM over and over again.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.numerical').on('click', function(){
        var clickednumber = $(this).val();
        $('#display').html($('#display').html()+clickednumber);
    });
});

<div id="calculator">
                <div id="display"></div>
                <button class="numerical" value="0">0</button>
                <button class="numerical" value="1">1</button>
                <button class="numerical" value="2">2</button>
                <button class="function" value="add">+</button>
                <button class="numerical" value="3">3</button>
                <button class="numerical" value="4">4</button>
                <button class="numerical" value="5">5</button>
                <button class="function" value="subtract">-</button>
                <button class="numerical" value="6">6</button>
                <button class="numerical" value="7">7</button>
                <button class="numerical" value="8">8</button>
                <button class="function" value="multiply">x</button>
                <button class="numerical" value="9">9</button>
                <button class="function" value="c">C</button>
                <button class="function" value="ce">CE</button>
                <button class="function" value="divide">/</button>
            </div>
        </center>
        <script src="calculator.js"></script>
```